# Basic create-react-app giving me these errors immediately before editing anything. What should i do?

Tags: reactjs

Attached is the picture of the errors I am getting. I will also copy and paste them below.

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
2The attempt to bind "/1-birthday-reminder/final/public/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" in the workspace failed as this URI is malformed.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an environment value called PUBLIC_URL comes with CRA which automaticaly gets absolute path of your project.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

This value seems to be not working correctly on your filesystem. It could be different reasons; miswritten env value, Operating System related problem, or etc.

In your public\index.html file; edit this lines(and other places where you see PUBLIC_URL) and give them path of the public folder manually.

```
 <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
```

like this; (This is example)

```
 <link rel="manifest" href="/1-birthday-reminder/final/public/manifest.json"/>
```

Dont forget to update them if you move folder in your filesystem or in server.